# Is it possible to change graphql schema once it is initialized

Tags: graphql-dotnet

I am using **graphql-dotnet** and populated schema based on different types (loaded from assembly). Now I would like to add new types to an existing schema without restarting the application server. Is that possible?

Comment: Which nuget package of graphql are you using?

Comment: I am using (GraphQL) https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL/